# window.open using JQuery wont open a JSP in a pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Friends

Im using a window.open even on a button and trying to load a jsp page that displayes the result, however Im not able to open the required JSP when I pass its name 
to achieve the popup opening using the

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

The code is as below in my pageOne.jsp

```
<input type="button" value="OPEN" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:8085/reports/popupData.jsp','Select Language','modal=yes,dialog=yes,width=200,height=360,resizable=no');" />
        <p id="text">Selected Languages are:</p>
```

Now I have tried the following options for strUrl to be passed as an argument

1. popupData.jsp

   - /reports/popupData.jsp
   - mylocation:8085/reports/popupData.jsp

Still nth works 
How do I make sure that strUrl location is right
Please let me know

Comment: A POPUP to select the language? We have 2013, not 1999! Consider using a nice inline dialog instead!

Answer (score 0):

To "make sure that strUrl location is right", open a new window or tab in your browser, paste `http://localhost:8085/reports/popupData.jsp` in the address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you can navigate to the page manually, then `strUrl` is correct.

You may be running into browser security issues, or pop-up blockers, as you are dealing with pop-up windows. A larger issue is that, with modern browsers, you cannot programmatically control whether your pop-up is opened in a new window or a new tab. This is left completely up to the control of the user.

The good news is that you've tagged this question as jQueryUI, so you have access to the jQuery UI Dialog widget. A simple change to your existing markup:

```
<input type="button" id="showLanguage" value="OPEN" />
<div id="dlg"></div>
```

and then a little bit o' scripting:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showLanguage').click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            "url": "http://localhost:8085/reports/popupData.jsp"
            "method": "GET",
            "dataType": "html",
            "success": function (data) {
                $('#dlg').html('<p id="text">Selected Languages are:</p>' + data).dialog({
                    "autoOpen": true,
                    "modal": true,
                    "title": "Select Language",
                    "width": 200,
                    "height": 360
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and voilà! You have a "pop-up window" as your interface intended without any of the "hassle" of modern browser security features (plus it's themeable, so it looks like part of your interface).

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MdwaG/

Comment: HI Pete , 
Thanks , I have two issues now , the popup.jsp has the checkboxes for each languages and when a user selects the check boxes and clicks on submit , the selected checkboxes values get displayed to the parent JSP . 
Here is the jsfiddle demo 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ps8Ly/1/show/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ps8Ly/show/
Please suggest